# Assigning to a pointer causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS through class_addMethod

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, method-swizzling

I have an internal class that adopts`UIScrollViewDelegate`, but does not implement `scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)`. I want to add this method to the class using `class_addMethod`, but unfortunately run into a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when trying to assign a new value to `targetContentOffset`.

Here is my code:

```
func extendDelegate(scrollViewDelegte: UIScrollViewDelegate) {
   let block : @convention(block) (UIScrollView, CGPoint, UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) -> Void = { scrollView, velocity, targetContentOffset  in
      // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here. 
      // I can read the pointee and it does contain a valid CGPoint value, 
      // however assigning to it gives a crash.
      targetContentOffset.pointee = .zero
   }

   class_addMethod(
      type(of: scrollViewDelegte),
      #selector(UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)),
      imp_implementationWithBlock(block),
      "v@:@{CGPoint=dd}^{CGPoint=dd}"
   )
}
```

Any helps is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And why can't you just add the method to your delegate class? Failing that, why can't you create a subclass of your delegate class with just the new method in?

Comment: It's an internal SwiftUI class, so there is no way to subclass it, nor extend it. The only way I can access it is during runtime, so that is why I resorted to this method.

Comment: If it's a class internal to `SwiftUI` you shouldn't be using it at all. Your code will be brittle at best and could break with every new release of SwiftUI. There's probably an official way to achieve what you are trying to achieve, so maybe if you explain it, somebody can give you an alternate answer.

Comment: Sure. Please explain how to adjust the target offset of a decelerating List view in SwiftUI without resorting back to a UIScrollView and loosing the lazy loading behaviour of List. List does use a a UIScrollView underneath anyways, which is easy to access but changing it's delegate to a custom object breaks it, so I would like to extend the original delegate with this method instead. I am open to any alternate suggestions that can achieve changing the target offset.

Comment: Try to do it in Objective-C. It's native. And pass NULL for types, it's already known from selector.

Comment: Why do you need to change the target offset. Won't that make the scroll view feel weird to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `imp_implementationWithBlock`'s documentation:

> The signature of block should be method_return_type `^(id self, method_args ...)`

I think you are missing self in parameters.

Comment: This actually solved it. I have no clue how are the two related but thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generating your own IMP and type encoding, I'd suggest you let the compiler do it for you, by creating a method normally, and transplanting it over:

```swift
import Foundation
import ObjectiveC

@objc class ScrollViewPatch: NSObject {
    @objc func scrollViewWillEndDragging(
        _ scrollView: UIScrollView,
        withVelocity velocity: CGPoint,
        targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>
    ) {
        targetContentOffset.pointee = .zero
    }
}

func extendDelegate(scrollViewDelegte: UIScrollViewDelegate) {
    let patchedMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(
        ScrollViewPatch.self,
        #selector(ScrollViewPatch.scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:))
    )!

    class_addMethod(
        type(of: scrollViewDelegte),
        #selector(UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)),
        method_getImplementation(patchedMethod),
        method_getTypeEncoding(patchedMethod) // Much more reliable than hard-coding "v@:@{CGPoint=dd}^{CGPoint=dd}"
    )
}
```

Here's a simpler standalone proof-of-concept:

```swift
import Foundation
import ObjectiveC

@objc class MethodSource: NSObject {
    @objc func myMethod(_ arg: NSString) {
        print("Called \(#function) on \(self) with \"\(arg)\"")
    }
}

@objc class TargetClass: NSObject {
    // Doens't natively respond to `-myMethod`
}

let targetObject = TargetClass()

// The target object doesn't initially respond to `-myMethod`
print(targetObject.responds(to: #selector(MethodSource.myMethod))) // false

let patchedMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(
    MethodSource.self,
    #selector(MethodSource.myMethod)
)!

class_addMethod(
    type(of: targetObject),
    #selector(MethodSource.myMethod),
    method_getImplementation(patchedMethod),
    method_getTypeEncoding(patchedMethod)
)

// Now it's true
print(targetObject.responds(to: #selector(MethodSource.myMethod)))

// Called myMethod(_:) on <main.TargetClass: 0x6000016b0040> with "some string"
targetObject.perform(#selector(MethodSource.myMethod), with: "some string")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will definetely change my implementation to this.

Comment: @BalázsVincze You should upvote answers if they helped you :) (including the other answer from Cy-4AH)